Is there a replacement for the IChainlinkOperator interface?
I have been working with Chainlink contracts from version 1.2.0. In that version, Chainlink used to have an IChainlinkOperator interface, which was used to map token symbols to their respective feed addresses.
Nevertheless, the latest version of Chainlink contracts no longer has an IChainlinkOperator interface.
I want to have need that same functionality by using the latest chainlink contracts. Is it true that the FeedRegistry.sol contract (https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/feed-registry) is facilitating that feature now?
What is the current best-practice if a protocol wants to have a central contract to call to retrieve price data for assets?
Should protocols then deploy their own FeedRegistry.sol contract and keep the feed addresses there and use that contract within their protocol code? If so, the new FeedRegistry.sol is not as minimalistic as the old IChainlinkOperator interface and holds way more functionality. Is it still desired for protocols to deploy a FeedRegistry.sol contract, regardless if it may holds a lot of redundant code that might not be utilized (if only wanting to utilize the old functionality that the IChainlinkOperator.sol interface specified?
Or is the current best-practice to just implement a custom contract that mimics the functionality that the old IChainlinkOperator interface specified? In that case, is it recommended to reuse the old IChainlinkOperator interface for the implementation?

@jonrsharpe - the FeedRegistry docs you linked to explains that its a way to pull price data from feeds without needing to know and supply specific feed addresses.  In what circumstances do you think you'd need to deploy a separate feed registry? what need do you have that is not being met with the current feed registry design?

@ZeusLawyer Imagine you want to deploy your own custom data feeds for pricing custom assets. In such a case, it would be good to also have a FeedRegistry contract to keep track of these feed addresses.

i see -- could your custom data feeds not simply be a "thin wrapper" around the data feeds registry contract? it would be useful to retain the chainlink consensus on data right?
